# Proguard: exclude external library jar from obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard

In my android project, I have a `libs/` directory under project root.

```
MyProject/
  - libs/
     - lib1.jar 
     - lib2.jar
```

In Eclipse, I added those jars to my build path.

In my proguard configuration, I try to exclude these jars from obfuscation. So I defined the following lines in **proguard.cfg**

```
-libraryjars /libs/lib1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/lib2.jar
```

But I got error :

```
Can't read [/libs/lib1.jar] (No such file or directory)
```

Then, I change to `-libraryjars /libs/lib1.jar` 
but I got `can't find referenced class` error which points to my lib's classes.

Where am I wrong in my configuration? What is the correct way of using `-libraryjars` in my case?

Comment: -libraryjars libs/lib1.jar
-libraryjars libs/lib2.jar

Comment: I have declared lib in this way

Comment: @Leem.fin : You did know how to use "Proguard: exclude external library jar from obfuscation"? Could u tell me how please, I'm stuck on it

Comment: remove '/' from beginning of path and it will become relative to the location of the config file.